# clicking right mouse button on upper-left corner crashes application while protection is on

Tags: c#, excel, crash

I've created an excel plugin which uses protection.

when I've got the protection active excel crashes when i click on the upper-left corner (selects all cells) first with the left mouse button (selecting all excel cells) and then with the right mouse button. There should have been a context menu, Instead the excel crashes.

How to solve this issue?

Here is my protection command:

```
getWorksheet().Protect(Properties.Settings.Default.worksheetPassword, false, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true);
```

Comment: I found it! Setting the tenth boolean to false solved the problem; this is 'AllowInsertingHyperlinks (true allows the user to insert hyperlinks on the worksheet.)'. For my application it was no problem not allowing hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Setting the tenth boolean to false solved the problem; this is 'AllowInsertingHyperlinks (true allows the user to insert hyperlinks on the worksheet.)'. For my application it was no problem not allowing hyperlinks.